# Run react app locally in production mode using vite?

Tags: reactjs, vite, production-environment

I would like to run a vite react app locally in production mode? What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: yarn build? then move the out/build folder into your local server

Comment: You can create a prod build and run `npx serve` command from the dist/build directory.

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma for you hints. Its working now, putting the solution the answer section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **package.json** file of you vite react app.

modify your script like that :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  }
}
```

**then run :**

```
npm run build

npm run serve
```